# How to do searching in Queue?

Tags: c++, queue

My code is working but there is still a problem so, technically it is not working. The problem that I encounter is that whenever I tried to search for my 2nd, 3rd and so on ID that I inputted command prompt is not working and then it exit.

Here is my code

```
void queue::qdisplay() // 7.2 ID CUSTOMER DETAILS
{
    int exist = 0;
    int C_id; 
    node *temp = front;
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Customer Details ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter customer ID: ";
    cin >> C_id;
      
    if (front == NULL)
          {
            cout << "No Information";
          }
    else
{
      while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp -> C_ID == C_id)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << "ID" << setw(20) << "Name: " << setw(10) << "Address" <<endl;
            cout << setw(5) << temp -> C_ID << setw(20) << temp -> C_name << setw(10) << temp -> C_address << endl;
            temp = temp->next;
            
            cout<< endl;
            exist = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(exist==0)
    {
        cout<<"MOVIE DOES NOT EXIST!!!"<<endl;
    }   
}
}
```

Comment: If `temp -> C_ID != C_id` you never change `temp` so your while loop will never terminate

Comment: What do I need to change?

Comment: `temp = temp->next;` is needed on every iteration.

Comment: What do you mean? on every iteration

Comment: This statement shall be executed every time you iterate the `while(temp!=NULL)` loop. In your code you change `temp` only if the condition is true, otherwise you get into an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried on changing the position of  `temp  = temp -> next;` but it still the same

Comment: Please be more specific than "is not working and then it exit". What exactly does (or doesn't) happen?

Comment: It terminates whenever I tried to search for the 2nd, 3rd, and so on customer ID. But if you tried to search your FIRST data that you input it display.

Comment: And what do you mean by "terminates"? Just disappears  without any further output, or something else?

Answer (score 0):

food is ok, please eat，

饭好了，请吃，

call once， searce once

调用一次，查询一次

if you want seach 2nd, 3rd

如果你想查第二个，第三个

do this,

你需要这样做

if you understand how to eated the food, please do accept

如果你懂我的意思，请点accept。

```c
yourQueue.qdisplay();
yourQueue.qdisplay();
yourQueue.qdisplay();
```

```c
void queue::qdisplay() // 7.2 ID CUSTOMER DETAILS
{
    int exist = 0;
    int C_id; 
    node *temp = front;
    cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Customer Details ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Enter customer ID: ";
    cin >> C_id;
      
    if (front == NULL)
          {
            cout << "No Information";
          }
    else
{
      while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        if (temp -> C_ID == C_id)
        {
            cout << setw(5) << "ID" << setw(20) << "Name: " << setw(10) << "Address" <<endl;
            cout << setw(5) << temp -> C_ID << setw(20) << temp -> C_name << setw(10) << temp -> C_address << endl;
            
            cout<< endl;
            exist = 1;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    if(exist==0)
    {
        cout<<"MOVIE DOES NOT EXIST!!!"<<endl;
    }   
}
}
```